# Disabling Nested MovieClips After Removing Parent Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In some of the level MovieClips I have for my Flash game, there is a certain MovieClip that controls a custom-built camera that I've created. Both the camera and the MovieClip function correctly and smoothly. However, whenever a level is completed and removed from the game, I get an `Error #1009` not recognizing the `checkCameraZoom` function. Also, this MovieClip is not added dynamically with code, but rather placed in the specified level MovieClips from the Library before run-time. Is there any possible way to fix this error?

ZoomOutArea Class:

```
package com.engine.assetHolders
{
    import com.engine.documentClass.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class ZoomOutArea extends MovieClip
    {
        public function ZoomOutArea():void
        {
            this.visible = false;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initZoomOutArea);
            // constructor code
        }
        public function initZoomOutArea(event:Event):void
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCameraZoom);
        }
        public function checkCameraZoom(event:Event):void
        {
            if (Document.getInstance != null)
            {
                if (this.hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent.parent).player.playerHitArea))
                {
                    this.hitTestZoom(0.6);
                }
                if (! this.hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent.parent).player.playerHitArea))
                {
                    this.hitTestZoom(1);
                }
            }
        }
        public function hitTestZoom(zoomLevel):Number
        {
            MovieClip(parent.parent).cameraScale = zoomLevel;
            return zoomLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can first make a dummy function, and see if it recognizes that "dummy" function or not. That may add up some clarity to situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register the class for `ENTER_FRAME` events when it's added to the stage, but you never unregister it. So that's why it keeps going even after it has been removed from the stage, and has no `parent` anymore.
You could add another listener for `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` and then remove the `checkCameraZoom` listener:

```
    public function initZoomOutArea(event:Event):void
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCameraZoom);
        this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);
    }

    private function onRemoved(event:Event):void
    {
         this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCameraZoom);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, it seems that I had totally forgotten about the `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` event listener...

Thank you very much for the help!